# Converting Select Box with Onchange to Select2

Tags: jquery-select2

I have a really long select box with an onchange function so that when the user selects a project, they are taken to the page for that project.

```
<select class="project-chooser" onchange="if (this.value) window.location.href=this.value">
<option value="http://projectpageurl.com">Project Title</option> 
<option value="http://projectpageurl2.com">Project Title 2</option> 
<option value="http://projectpageurl3.com">Project Title 3</option> 
</select>
```

Since there are so many options, I'd like to convert this to Select2 so the user can search, but don't know how to get the same effect once I apply Select2 to my dropdown. The onchange is stripped out. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use select2:select event like this

```
 $('.project-chooser').on('select2:select', function (evt) {
     window.location.href=$(this).val();
});
```

here is working example
https://jsfiddle.net/yek6bkfs/

Comment: Cool enjoy coding :)